# Как управлять памятью в многопоточном приложении на WIN API?

Tags: c, winapi

Собственно есть приложение на Си, в нем используются такие нехорошие вещи как malloc, realloc, memset. Все работает хорошо до тех пор пока не запускается поток, после этого программа крешится. Поток создается через CreateThread, я не хочу использовать CLR в коде. Вопрос как управлять памятью используя чисто Си функции и Win API ?

**UPD**
Поток крешиться из за использования функций работы с памятью стандартной библиотеки Си, повреждается куча, эксепшн в функции _heap_alloc();

### **Создание потока**

```
ThreadID = CreateThread(0, NULL,
(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&ThreadFunction, 
&DataForThreadFunction, 0, &ThreadIdentifier);
```

`DataForThreadFunction` - выделенна через `malloc`. Она нигде не освобождается.
Внутри `ThreadFunction` нет выделения памяти или освобождения памяти.
Без запуска потока приложение не падает. Память не течет.

Comment: Управляйте памятью внимательно и аккуратно.

Comment: Вопрос в том, че юзать CLR эквиваленты или WIN API или просто как то "управлять внимательно и аккуратно" что бы это черт возьми не значило.

Comment: На этот вопрос можно дать слишком много ответов, либо же качественные ответы будут слишком длинными для данного формата. Пожалуйста, уточните подробности, чтобы сократить количество ответов или выделить проблему, ответ на которую будет занимать пару абзацев.

Comment: @iDarkLord, попробуйте создать *минимальный законченный пример* и мы попытаемся найти место, где вы либо сами портите память, либо вызываете не thread-safe функции (знаете, что это такое?).

Comment: Я везде вызываю не thread-safe функции в этом то как бы и проблема)). Вопрос в том чем их заменить.

Answer (score 2):

@iDarkLord, Вы пишете

> Я везде вызываю не thread-safe функции в этом то как бы и проблема)). Вопрос в том чем их заменить.

Их надо не заменять, а обрамлять мьютексами. Т.е. вызовы  одной и той же не  thread-safe функции из разных потоков должны разделяться по времени. Если разные функции вызывают внутри одну и ту же тоже не tread-safe функцию, то доступ к ним должен разграничиваться одинаковым мьютексом.

Я понимаю, что в общем случае узнать это невозможно, поэтому для надежности вызовы всех "ненадежных" функций придется разделять.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в использовании memcpy. Ошибочно копировался блок памяти большего размера чем было выделено. Забавно, что без использования потока программа работает и не падает. Память действительно не текла поскольку я лишь немного залезал в чужую память.

Comment: Теперь понятно, почему Вам никто не ответил на Ваш вопрос? Программы падают из-за конкретной реализации, а не из-за того, что Вы выбрали неправильную технологию.

Comment: @atwice, я понял что от вас никакого толку.